# NSIS - Adding other type of files

Tags: nsis

I have a NSIS generated-installer, however, I would like to add other files to the installer at compile time. For example, I want to add a batch file to the installer, so when the .exe file is ran, I can call that batch file within the .exe without needing to copy the actual batch file to the output location. This means the batch file will actually exist within the installer.

I hope this makes sense and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A batch file has to be extracted somewhere before it can be executed. $PluginsDir is a good choice because it is deleted when the installer ends.

```
Section
SetOutPath $Instdir
File myfiles\*

InitPluginsDir
SetOutPath $PluginsDir
File file.bat
nsExec::Exec '"cmd.exe" /c if 1==1 "$PluginsDir\file.bat"'
Pop $0 ; Exit code
SetOutPath $Temp ; Don't hold lock on pluginsdir
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there a way to get the actual batch file to be in the installer. For example, if at the compile time the batch file exist, then add it, so that means if the .exe is ran other other machines it will still execute the batch file as it will exist within the installer itself.

Comment: Did you even try my code? The batch file is included in the .exe

Comment: Ahh Yes!, apologies for the hesitation. Thank you soo much for your help.